# How to update options of an existing google chart in a wrapper

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I change / update an existing google chart's options. Let's say I want to with a click of a button apply these options to an existing chart:

```
var options = {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
};
```

and yes, I do know that you can do al this with the chartEditor but that solution will not work for me in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your chart is a `ChartWrapper`in a `Dashboard`, you may be inspired by 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#8-programmatic-changes-after-draw

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      function drawStuff() {

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
          document.getElementById('programmatic_dashboard_div'));

        var programmaticSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'programmatic_control_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten',
            'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical'
            }
          }
        });

        // We omit "var" so that programmaticChart is visible to changeOptions().
        programmaticChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'programmatic_chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'legend': 'none',
            'chartArea': {
              'left': 15,
              'top': 15,
              'right': 0,
              'bottom': 0
            },
            'pieSliceText': 'value'
          }
        });

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael', 5],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);

        dashboard.bind(programmaticSlider, programmaticChart);
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeOptions();">
  Change Options
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeOptions() {
    programmaticChart.setOptions({
      width: 400,
      height: 240,
      title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
      colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
    });
    programmaticChart.draw();
  }
</script>
<div id="programmatic_dashboard_div">
  <div id="programmatic_control_div"></div>
  <div id="programmatic_chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tested it with my code... works great. You know what. I actually wanted to do it like you did but was missing one thing :) the comment in your code
" We omit "var" so that programmaticChart is visible to changeOptions()." made all the difference :) thank you again Paul, you have no idea how much easier this next week will be for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Call the `draw()` function with the new options

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

var changeOptions; // global variable for callback function

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
  data.addRows([
      ['one',5],
      ['two',15],
      ['three',8]
  ]);

  var options = {
      title: 'Original Title',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

  // function to change options on button click
  changeOptions = function() {
      // define new options
      options.width = 200;
      options.height = 200;
      options.title = 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza';
      options.colors = ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'];
       // call draw() with new options 
      chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeOptions();">change options</button>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```